# How do you find the appropriate sticker in LittleBigPlanet?

Tags: little-big-planet-vita

I'm playing LittleBigPlanet on the PS Vita. When I see place for sticker it's always a problem to find the required one. Is there any tool in game to help? Because finding it in huge list is an issue.

Maybe they are categorized in some reasonable way?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to stickers spots, these places in the level where you need a specific sticker to unlock some stuff.

If you have the required sticker, it'll always appear in the first sticker page, just below the Functions, under a category named **Switch Triggers**.

If you don't see a category named Switch Triggers, or you don't see an appropriate sticker under it, it means you don't have the required sticker yet. Just keep playing through the campaign and you should get it.